# Can I keep the OS as-is, on swapping SSD on compatible Macbooks?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hard-drive, ssd

I own two Macbooks, an Air mid-2013 (256gb) and a Pro Early-2015 (128gb). As far as I know their ssd drives are the same model.

The question I would like to ask is: 
Can I take the SSD drive from the Air mid-2013 and install it inside the Pro early-2015 and use the OS, with all the data, as was installed on the original Mac? Or would I need to reinstall the OS on the newer Mac?

Comment: Don't do that - also counts the internal hardware - microprocessor used, chipset, and peripherals. MBA has some more USB/other ports than MBP. Only if internal hardware is the same, which I do not think.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can replace it without reinstalling the OS and keep the data. 
The only issue you can face is a long time first boot.

But I recommend you to backup both disks to external drive like a Time Capsule or external hard drive before replacing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, sometimes it does mean you may need to apply firmware updates on the target machine before you do it if the OS is much newer than what the target was shipped with.